# How do you updated loaded image from a menu selection using Python ktinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Using python's tkinter, I am trying to write this drop down menu where I can choose 3 options. for each option it will display a different image. what I have so far:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    
def change_image(event):
    selected_option = var.get()
    
    if selected_option == "Option 1":
        image_path = "image1.png"
    elif selected_option == "Option 2":
        image_path = "image2.png"
    elif selected_option == "Option 3":
        image_path = "image3.png"
    
    new_image = Image.open(image_path)
    new_image = new_image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image)
    img_label.configure(image=photo)
    img_label.image = photo
    
#Create the main application window
root = tk.Tk()root.title("Dropdown Menu Example")
#Create a dropdown menu
options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
var = tk.StringVar(root)
var.set(options[0])   
    
# Set the default         
optiondropdown = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *options, command=change_image)
optiondropdown.pack(pady=10)
#Load and display the initial image
initial_image = Image.open("image1.png")
initial_image = initial_image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
initial_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(initial_image)
img_label = tk.Label(root, image=initial_photo)
img_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

the result is: it will display image1.png, but clicking the update Image button after choosing option 2 or option 3 do not update the image to either image2.png or image3.png.

the output is:

[image]

I have 3 image files in my directory. As click option 2 in the drop down menu, the image2.png should have been displayed, for the same scenario, if I choose the options 3 the image3.png should have been displayed.

Comment: Fix the code formatting.

Comment: From the error traceback, the line that causes the exception is `img_label.configure(image=image)`, but there is only `img_label.configure(image=photo)` in the posted code.

Comment: Your code works for me, Windows 10, Python 3.11, Pillow 9.5, it only gives a warning ` DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use LANCZOS or Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
   new_image = new_image.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)`